# Type inference in where clauses

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference

If I write

```
foo :: [Int]
foo = iterate (\x -> _) 0
```

GHC happily tells me that `x` is an `Int` and that the hole should be another `Int`. However, if I rewrite it to

```
foo' :: [Int]
foo' = iterate next 0
  where next x = _
```

it has no idea what the type of `x`, nor the hole, is. The same happens if I use `let`.

Is there any way to recover type inference in `where` bindings, other than manually adding type signatures?

Comment: Write a hole instead of `next` to obtain the type you need to fill in, so `iterate _ 0`, then you know what the type of `next` should be.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work if I have already written half of `next` and need to figure out what I need for the rest.  `iterate _ 0` is useful for figuring out what signature to put on `next`, but I would prefer not having to do that at all.

Comment: This is happening because of something called "let-generalization". Some additional information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452343/stripping-out-let-in-haskell/23452841

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.  This behavior is by design and is inherited from the theoretical Hindley-Milner type system that formed the initial inspiration for Haskell's type system.  (The behavior is known as "let-polymoprhism" and is arguably the most critical feature of the H-M system.)

Roughly speaking, lambdas are typed "top-down":  the expression `(\x -> _)` is first assigned the type `Int -> Int` when type-checking the containing expression (specifically, when type-checking `iterate`'s arguments), and this type is then used to infer the type of `x :: Int` and of the hole `_ :: Int`.

In contrast, `let` and `where`-bound variables are typed "bottom-up".  The type of `next x = _` is inferred first, independently of its use in the main expression, and once that type has been determined, it's checked against its use in the expression `iterate next 0`.  In this case, the expression `next x = _` is inferred to have the rather useless type `p -> t`.  Then, that type is checked against its use in the expression `iterate next 0` which specializes it to `Int -> Int` (by taking `p ~ Int` and `t ~ Int`) and successfully type-checks.

In languages/type-systems without this distinction (and ignoring recursive bindings), a `where` clause is just syntactic sugar for a lambda binding and application:

```
foo = expr1 where baz = bazdefn   ==>   foo = (\baz -> expr1) bazdefn
```

so one thing you *could* do is "desugar" the `where` clause to the "equivalent" lambda binding:

```
foo' :: [Int]
foo' = (\next -> iterate next 0) (\x -> _)
```

This syntax is physically repulsive, sure, but it works.  Because of the top-down typing of lambdas, both `x` and the hole are typed as `Int`.